# Servelt Page doesn't Redirect to second Page using Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

I am a beginner of servlet jsp. I am creating a simple login form if the login successful page redirects to the second servlet along with the username. but it doesn't work it shows the error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path second does not start with a "/" character**
what I tried so far I attached below.

**Form**

```
 <div class="row">
                <form method="POST" action="login">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="uname" class="form-control"> 
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="pword" name="pword" placeholder="pword" class="form-control">

                </div>


                 <div class="form-group">


                     <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">

                </div>

                </form>


            </div>
```

**Login** Servlet Page

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class login extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

         String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
         String pass = request.getParameter("pword");

         if(uname.equals("John") && pass.equals("123"))
         {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
            session.putValue("username", uname);

            ServletContext context=getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd=context.getRequestDispatcher("second");  

            rd.forward(request, response);  

         }



    }
```

**Second Servlet Page**

```
@WebServlet("/second")
public class second extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
       String uname = (String)session.getValue("uname");
        out.println("User Name is " + uname);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some big differences between `redirect` and `forward` . [This](https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-redirect-forward) article will help you to understand better your problem.

Some things to keep in mind from the article :

**FORWARD**

1) *Request and response objects will remain the same object after forwarding. Request-scope objects will be still available* (this is why if you try to add the "/" you get the 405 status - it will try to forward you to the "/second" servlet but the only request overridden  is `GET`)

**REDIRECT**

1) *The request is redirected to a different resource*

2) *A new request is created*

So instead of using `rd.forward` I would suggest you to use the `sendRedirect()` method from `HttpServletResponse` class.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/second");
```

**AND** the correct way to get the session username attribute is this:

```
String uname = (String) session.getValue("username");
```

Otherwise it will try to look after **uname** key which is **not** set. The `uname` was only a value mapped to the **username** key ( `session.putValue("username",uname);`

Comment: how to write it sir sendRedirect()

Comment: now it is working  User Name is null  . User Name is not passing

Comment: The correct way to get the username from session is this : `session.getValue("username")`. Because **uname** was only a value mapped to the **username** key.

Comment: HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String uname = (String)session.getValue("uname");
        out.println("User Name is " + uname);   i used it in my second page but username getting null

Answer (score 0):

this exception indicates, path does not start with a "/".
try below instead.

```
 RequestDispatcher rd=context.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath() +"/second");
```

Comment: i tried this sir i got the error HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Comment: i attached folder structure of project above